# Axios post method is not available

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

I wanted to implement a post call with axios in my vue application, but the method doesn't exists.

The implementation of axios should be fine, because I can use axios.get(), but unfortunately axios.post() is not available.

[image]

In the package.json I got it as dependency:

```
"dependencies": {
"axios": "^0.21.4",
```

Does someone know, what I did wrong?

Cheers,
Michael

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the IDE is looking for a implementation of `axios.post()` without parameters, which does not exist. The only implementation of `axios.post()` is with a address parameter and a body parameter. Ie: `axios.post("www.mywebsite.com", body)`

Comment: I already tested it with parameters, but nothing is gonna happen, when I execute it

Comment: I tested it again. You are right. It is just an IDE thing...